# How to get cell formats from XLSX files in Perl?

Tags: excel, perl

I am able to find $cell->get_format() or $cell->format _hash in .xls files parser but not for xlsx format. I am also open to use any XLSX parser for reading the spreadsheet. Basically I am copying one spreadsheet to another preserving the format.

I am new to the Perl, Please bear up with me if it's very basic. The below code works fine copying in excel value to another. I am having trouble copying the format. I need to copy the format value from the reading file and then assign it to writing cell- self is the variable need to change.

The question I have asked Earlier 
[How to copy the format of the .xlsx cell using "Excel::Writer::XLSX" reader to the copied cell using "Spreadsheet::WriteExcel" writer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60642092/how-to-copy-the-format-of-the-xlsx-cell-using-excelwriterxlsx-reader-to-t)
And I am open to any other XLSX parser in case this is not the right to copy the format of the cell.

Answer (score 1):

These modules cannot modify spreadsheets in place, so you need a reader and a writer. To read an XLSX file, use [Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX) which implements the same methods as [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel) but parses XLSX files, so its cells also have [get_format](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Cell#get_format()) which returns the properties [listed here](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel#Format). To write a new spreadsheet use [Excel::Writer::XLSX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX), which implements the same methods as [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel) but creates XLSX files. You would add formats to such a new sheet as [described here](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX#CELL-FORMATTING).

Comment: what should I use in place of "CELL_FORMAT" to copy the format of cell:- $sheet_write->write($row, $col,$cell -> value,"CELL_FORMAT");          If I use  $sheet_write->write($row, $col,$cell -> value,call->get_format(); then I get error and can't open generated .XLSX file.

Comment: You can't use the format objects directly from the parser. You have to create a format in the new worksheet using ->add_format, then you can pass that format object.

Comment: @ Grinnz  Please check below for my answer. Though I am still getting the broken .xlsx output file.

Comment: can I copy $format= $cell->get_format();
after adding this "my $format = $excel_2->add_format()" to my code.

Comment: No. You must add a format to the worksheet for each format you want to use from the source file.